# GCS: Manually trigger "object created" event

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Cloud Function that is being triggered by new objects creation in a GCS bucket.

Sometimes things go wrong and the GCF fails. I know that I can enable automatic retry. Still, it would be nice to be able to trigger "object created" event for existing objects during development/debugging. How do I do that?

Comment: Modify your Function to **capture** an event and save it to Cloud Storage. Then you can use the CLI **curl** to call your Function with the saved event (JSON) as the payload.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `test` tab of the function ? You can send a `json` object with the same information of the create trigger of the gcs. I have saved the steps I took for this [here](https://github.com/ewertonvsilva/stackoverflow/blob/main/71076229/object_create_gcf.md) let me know if does help.

Comment: For that kind of use case, I recommend to redesign your application. Use Cloud Storage notification to create event in PubSub, and create an HTTP functions that receive PubSub push messages in HTTP. Like that, it will be easier to invoke your Cloud Functions with the HTTP request that you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example on how to simulate a file upload event trig:

#### User a function to print a event result, so you can have a template of how is the event data:

```py
def hello_gcs(event, context):
    """Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    print(event)
```

#### Get the json result in the logs:

[image]

#### Use the tests tab to resend the same json object when you want for test (logs result can take some time)

You have to format the json before use because you have to use `"` insteade of `'`. Use [this site](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#)

[image]

---

Json example:

```json
{
   "bucket":"<bucket name>",
   "contentType":"image/png",
   "crc32c":"a1/tEw==",
   "etag":"9999999999999999/UCEAE=",
   "generation":"9999999999999999",
   "id":"<bucket name>/<file name>",
   "kind":"storage#object",
   "md5Hash":"9999999999999999==",
   "mediaLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/<bucket name>/o/<file name>?generation=9999999999999999&alt=media",
   "metageneration":"1",
   "name":"Screenshot 2022-02-10 6.09.37 PM.png",
   "selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<bucket name>/o/<file name>",
   "size":"452941",
   "storageClass":"STANDARD",
   "timeCreated":"2022-02-11T10:22:01.919Z",
   "timeStorageClassUpdated":"2022-02-11T10:22:01.919Z",
   "updated":"2022-02-11T10:22:01.919Z"
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the only option I have. Thanks :)